# Drawing multiple layers from vector tile in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, postgis, vector-tiles

I'm creating vector tiles with Postgis (ST_AsMVT()) and rendering them with OpenLayers (ol/layer/VectorTile) and styling them with style file (ol-mapbox-style). I have multiple layers in one pbf file.
How can I control the drawing order (z-order) of those layers included in one pbf file?

Comment: As with mapbox the rendering order is based on the order of the layer definitions in the style json.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work also in OpenLayers.